# Spring Boot using lazy

Tags: spring-mvc, lazy-loading, hibernate-mapping

I have a problem , I created two entity's , driver and vehicle , with relationship one to many.

**driver**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="email")
private String email;

@JsonIgnore
@JsonSerialize
@Lazy
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY ,mappedBy="driver",
           cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                     CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
private List<Vehicle> Vehicles;
```

**vehicle**
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

```
@Column(name="plate_number")
private String plateNumber;

@Column(name="vehicle_type")
private String vehicleType;

@ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
         CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name="driver_id")
private Driver driver;
```

I don't know why it's loading the vehicle data at start :(

how do I use lazy on my code ?

[database relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6HFB.png)

[postman - JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhSj6.png)

Comment: how did you see vehicle data is loaded? did you check how many times query executed when you try to see vehicle data?

Comment: I added a link postman - JSON , you can see over there my result , the vehicle data is loaded

Comment: "did you check how many times query executed when you try to see vehicle data?"

Comment: no , I didn't check how many times query executed

Comment: What is the purpose of having both `@JsonIgnore`
`@JsonSerialize` on the property.

Comment: I solve the problem by using JsonIgnoreProperties , with that I can load the data that I want .

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization